# Context behind this hadith on Ramadan

Tags: halal-haram, hadith-interpretation

> The Prophet said, “Verily, Gabriel came to me and he said: Whoever reaches the month of Ramadan and he is not forgiven, then he will enter Hellfire and Allah will cast him far away, so say ameen. I said ameen.

I know I’ve asked this question before but I need to know the context behind this Hadith. It makes me more worried that no one answers this question. I’m just scared because I feel like I wasted my Ramadan. I fasted the entire month but I missed so many prayers due to laziness and some personal issues especially on the last ten days. I also had some small arguments with my parents. I repented for that but I still feel guilty. Does this mean I won’t ever be forgiven and I’m going straight to Hell? Even if the answer is something bad I’d still appreciate if someone helps me out and lets me know, please.

Answer (score 0):

We can not know for certain if Allah has forgiven us. But as this hadith says you reached Ramadan and did your wajib(obligatory) actions like fasting and praying. What you did was not sin, it was just not the best thing to do.
So InshaAllah you are forgiven. Allah is compassionate and merciful, if someone asks for forgiveness he will give it to them.